# Espver V5 vs Esper 8.5 performace of loading statements at Start up

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

We are using an executor service to load all statements in Esper runtime while server starts. Exact similar configurations are used(w.r.t. inbound thread pool param and everything else) in both version i.e. V5 and V8.5 but loading time in V8.5 is much more than earlier version.
What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

Esper 8.5 is a compiler and runtime. The compiler takes more time to produce JVM byte code. You can however compile once and store the result. Or compile in parallel to deploying.

Comment: How do we achieve complie once and store the result? and  compile in parallel to deploying.? If you can guide me please.

Comment: In esper 8.5 it is taking more than 20 minutes to load 3500+ statements whereas in esper 5 it was taking only 17 seconds. 
Difference should not be this big. 

what could be the problem any thought?